# flot curved line start with first point

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I am using flotjs plugin to create a graph.
In my example first curve line start with (0,0) but I need my line starts with (20,20) I mean start with the first point instead of (0,0)... look at my second example the lines are started with first point not from (0,0) position.i need the same pattern on curved graph too. how can I do this?

```js
//data
var d1 = [[null,],[20, 20], [25, 50], [27.5, 35], [30, 20], [35, 20]];

//flot options
var options = {
                 series: {
                     curvedLines: {active: true}
                 }              };

//plotting
$.plot($("#flotContainer"),[
    {
        data: d1, color: '#2b8cbe',
        lines: {show: true, lineWidth: 3},
        //choose tension from [0,1] to see overshooting effects (0.5 is default)
        curvedLines: {apply: true, tension: 1}
    }, {
        data: d1, color: '#f03b20',
       points: {show: true}
    }    
], options);

$.plot($("#flotContainer2"),[
    {
        data: d1, color: '#2b8cbe',
        lines: {show: true, lineWidth: 3},
        //monotonicFit enforces monotonicity
        curvedLines: {apply: true, monotonicFit: true}
    }, {
        data: d1, color: '#f03b20',
        points: {show: true}
    }    
], options);
```

```css
.chart-style {
    width: 400px;
    height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/flot/flot/v0.8.3/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/MichaelZinsmaier/CurvedLines/master/curvedLines.js"></script>
<h4>CurvedLines: with standard settings (shows effects of tension parameter)</h4>
<div id="flotContainer" class="chart-style"></div>

<h4>CurvedLines: with monotonicFit (no overshooting/wiggles) </h4>
<div id="flotContainer2" class="chart-style"></div>
```

but its working fine on line chart

```js
var data = [
    {
     label: 'foo',
     color: 'red',
     data: [[0,null],[1, 300], [2, 300], [3, 300], [4, 300], [5, 300]]},
     {
     label: 'bar',
     color: 'blue',
     data: [[1, 800], [2, 600], [3, 400], [4, 200], [5, 0]]},
     {    label: 'baz',
     olor: 'yellow',
     data: [[1, 100], [2, 200], [3, 300], [4, 400], [5, 500]]},
     {
     label: 'dart',
     color: 'green',
     data: [[1, 500], [2, 350], [3, 400], [4, 700], [5, 50]]}
    ];

var flot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true
            
        },
        points:{
        show:true
        }
       
      },
     legend: {
         noColumns: 4,
         container: $("#chartLegend")
     }
  });
```

```css
#chartLegend .legendLabel { padding-right:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/flot/flot/v0.8.3/jquery.flot.js"></script>

    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
    <div id="chartLegend"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curvedLines plugin uses your first data point `[null,]` and converts it to `[0,0]`. Remove that datapoint and the curve starts at `[20,20]`.

```js
//data
var d1 = [
  [20, 20],
  [25, 50],
  [27.5, 35],
  [30, 20],
  [35, 20]
];

//flot options
var options = {
  series: {
    curvedLines: {
      active: true
    }
  }
};

//plotting
$.plot($("#flotContainer"), [{
  data: d1,
  color: '#2b8cbe',
  lines: {
    show: true,
    lineWidth: 3
  },
  //choose tension from [0,1] to see overshooting effects (0.5 is default)
  curvedLines: {
    apply: true,
    tension: 1
  }
}, {
  data: d1,
  color: '#f03b20',
  points: {
    show: true
  }
}], options);

$.plot($("#flotContainer2"), [{
  data: d1,
  color: '#2b8cbe',
  lines: {
    show: true,
    lineWidth: 3
  },
  //monotonicFit enforces monotonicity
  curvedLines: {
    apply: true,
    monotonicFit: true
  }
}, {
  data: d1,
  color: '#f03b20',
  points: {
    show: true
  }
}], options);
```

```css
.chart-style {
  width: 400px;
  height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/flot/flot/v0.8.3/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/MichaelZinsmaier/CurvedLines/master/curvedLines.js"></script>
<h4>CurvedLines: with standard settings (shows effects of tension parameter)</h4>
<div id="flotContainer" class="chart-style"></div>

<h4>CurvedLines: with monotonicFit (no overshooting/wiggles) </h4>
<div id="flotContainer2" class="chart-style"></div>
```

Comment: [, null] its leaving space on flot chart.because I don't want my first point start with on 1 yaxis .you can see exact solution here https://github.com/MichaelZinsmaier/CurvedLines/pull/35